# Spring MVC handling session expired

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, session-timeout

I'm working with `Jboss EAP 6.2`, `Java EE 6` and `Spring MVC 4.0.2`.
When the session expired I want to execute a page redirect.

I have developed a Spring Interceptor

```
@Component
public class SessionExpiredInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SessionExpiredInterceptor.class);
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
     final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
         if ( session == null || session.isNew() ) {
             ConfigurationProperties confProp = ConfigurationProperties.getInstance();
             logger.info("Sessione scaduta, redirect home page");
             request.getSession(true);
             response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/" + 
                     confProp.getInstance().getProperty("session.expired.redirect"));
         } 
        return true;

    }
}
```

but I have the following exeception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.navigator': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000043: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:676)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
    it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.web.mvc.model.Navigator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6b810e.addNavigationMessages(<generated>)
    it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.web.mvc.UserSessionInterceptor.preHandle(UserSessionInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBWEB000043: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2627)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2361)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSession(ServletRequestAttributes.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSessionMutex(ServletRequestAttributes.java:212)
    org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:338)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:676)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
    it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.web.mvc.model.Navigator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b6b810e.addNavigationMessages(<generated>)
    it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.web.mvc.UserSessionInterceptor.preHandle(UserSessionInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

The navigator bean is injected in some @Controller and other Interceptor.

This is a Interceptor that use `Navigator` bean:

```
    @Component
    public class UserSessionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Navigator navigator;


        static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserSessionInterceptor.class.getName());

        public static ConfigurationProperties getAuthenticationProps() throws IOException {
            return ConfigurationProperties.getInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception { 
...}
}
```

The following is the interceptor configuration in `spring.xml`

```
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/**" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/index.jsp" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/logout" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/ajax-logout" />
    <bean class="it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.web.mvc.SessionExpiredInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptor> 


<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/home"/>
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/static/**" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/logout" />
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/ajax-logout" />
    <bean class="it.lispa.sire.finanziamentionline.web.mvc.UserSessionInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Can you help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us where your `navigator` bean is declared and where it is injected?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is injected in some controller and other Spring Inspector

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i have inserted it in the question. Thanks

Comment: The `preHandle` at the beginning of your question is in `SessionExpiredInterceptor`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens here is that `SessionExpiredInterceptor` acts before `UserSessionInterceptor`. If it detects that the session is new, it performs a redirect

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/" + 
    confProp.getInstance().getProperty("session.expired.redirect"));
```

Once you do a redirect, you've basically stated that you're finished processing the request and have sent a response (301 status code). But instead, in your code, you are returning `true` from `preHandle` which indicates to the `DispatcherServlet` that it should continue handling the request, execute the other interceptors and eventually reach the `@Controller`.

You don't want this. In the `if` block, return `false` after the `sendRedirect`.