# How to redirect to login page on session time out using Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, session

I have below configuration in my security context

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"
    secured-annotations="enabled">
    <!-- <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/> -->
</global-method-security>

<security:http pattern="/pages/common/UnAuthorized.html*"
    security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/resources/images/*" security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/Logout.html*"
    security="none" />
<security:http pattern="/SessionTimeout.html*"
    security="none" />

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="fullyAuthenticated" />
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"
        ref="siteminderFilter" />
    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SMSESSION"
        invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/Logout.html" />
    <security:session-management
        invalid-session-url="/SessionTimeout.html">
         <security:concurrency-control expired-url="/pages/common/SessionTimeout.html" />
    </security:session-management>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />
```

And registered an event in web.xml along with session-timeout configuration

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>localDeploymentFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
 <filter>
 <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
</filter-class>
</filter>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I am not sure in what I am missing here. But the url is not getting redirected to the sessiontimeout page.

When I tried to debug the springs code, I saw that only "RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy" is getting called and the new session are getting created using the existing session. I am expecting some code which will redirect to the session expiry URL. But I didnt find any during the debug.

**Update:**
I am using Angular JS (Single page application) and There is no login screen for our app. the login happens via siteminder.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658203/spring-mvc-handling-session-expired.

Comment: I am new to Spring and we  are not using Spring MVC. Can you please tell me if I can still use this code somehow?